# how to call api after refresh token in reactjs with using react-fetching-library

Tags: reactjs

**Hi, i m working on project with reactjs and using tokens and refresh token. after 401 error i m able to call APIs. APIs response showing 200 in network tab but data not updating in components.**

**refresh token call**

```
 const responseInterceptor =  (client: any) => async (action:any, response:any) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      const tokens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokens'));
    if(response.status===401){
      fetch(`api.com/refresh_Token`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          refreshToken: tokens.refreshToken,
          Accept: 'application.json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ucc_pan: "string" }) ,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>{
        console.log(response, "response33")
        // alert(response);
        setItem("tokens", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        fetch(action.endpoint, {
          method: action.method,
          body:action.payload,
          headers: {
            accessToken: response.data.accessToken,
            Accept: 'application.json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
      }) 
      }) 
    }
      return response;
    };
    
    const clientOption = createClient({
      requestInterceptors: [requestHostInterceptor(API_URL)],
      responseInterceptors: [responseInterceptor],
      // cacheProvider: cache,
    });
    export const client = clientOption;
    export const ClientContextProvider = CCP;
```

Comment: you can try to modify the response interceptor to return a Promise that resolves with the updated response after the refresh token API call completes

Comment: @Nafis how can i use Promise with shared code. please help me bcz i m not using axios

Answer (score 0):

```
  const responseInterceptor = (client: any) => async (action:any, response:any) => {
      const tokens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokens'));
      if (response.status === 401) {
        return fetch(api.com/refresh_Token, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            refreshToken: tokens.refreshToken,
            Accept: 'application.json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ ucc_pan: "string" }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response, "response33");
            setItem("tokens", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            // Update the original request with the new access token and retry
            const updatedRequest = {
              ...action,
              headers: {
                ...action.headers,
                accessToken: response.data.accessToken,
              },
            };
            return client(updatedRequest);
          });
      }
      return response;
    };
    
    const clientOption = createClient({
      requestInterceptors: [requestHostInterceptor(API_URL)],
      responseInterceptors: [responseInterceptor],
    });
    
    export const client = clientOption;
    
    export const ClientContextProvider = CCP;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. its working same like previously